# sqlalchemy: filter() not properly working because of missing mapper attribute/AttributeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My SQLAlchemy 0.8 code looks like:

model.py:

```
from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper

class Food(object):
    pass

def initialize_model(metadata):
    FoodTable = Table('food', metadata, schema='food', autoload=True)
    globals()['Food'] = mapper(Food, FoodTable)
```

app.py

```
engine = create_engine(dsn, convert_unicode=True)$
metadata = MetaData(engine)$

import xxx.core.model$
xxx.core.model.initialize_model(metadata)$

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, twophase=True))

from xxx.core.model import Food
results = session.query(Food).filter(Food.nbo_no==query)
```

This gives me an AttributeError for Food.ndb_no although the Food Table contains this
column 'ndb_no'. Why isn't this column mapped to the 'Food' mapper?

Comment: Why not use declarative mapping? Or at least mark `Food` as a global instead of poking into `globals()`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using declarative layer and passing the Base directly to the initialize_model() method:

```
  9 def initialize_model(Base):
 10     
 11     class Food(Base, Mixin):
 12         __tablename__ = 'food'
 13         __table_args__ = {'schema': 'food', 'autoload': True}
 14     globals()['Food'] = Food
```